# What is correct answer for an intersection problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

please help with correct answer regarding this intersection issue: If the set $A=\{0,2,4,6\}$ and $B=\{\{0\},\{2\},\{4\},\{6\}\}$
is $A\cap B=∅$ or $A\cap B=\{0\}$?

Comment: Please include your own efforts on solving the problem.

Comment: The elements of set B are themselves sets.  Does set A contain any elements that are themselves sets?

Answer (score 3):

Your second option can't be right, because $0\notin B$. Moreover, if it were right, why just $0$ and not $2,4$ and $6$, too?
In fact, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, since none of the elements of $A$ is equal to an element of $B$, for example $0\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: This is a correct answer. That said, please don't  post answers to questions where the OP shows no work of their own. The most you should have done here was post a comment with a hint. Or, better, comment asking the OP to show some effort.

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Also, unfortunately I'm not allowed to comment yet because I'm a new user, but I still wanted to help. But thank you for the reminder, I'm going to consider it the next time.